# Half an hour layover in Vienna between international flights

Tags: transit, short-connections, vie

I arrive from an internal flight in Vienna and have half an hour layover in Vienna for my next international flight, booked as one ticket. No other possible flight. Will I make it? If not, then what?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Can you be more specific about your connection? Flights within Schengen countries, for example, are international but from the passengers' perspective are much like domestic flights.

Comment: "If not, then what?": They'll book you on the next flight.  If that flight isn't on the same day, they'll put you in a hotel.

Comment: **What phoog said**

Comment: The countries in question would be helpful. I'm guessing that while your second flight is international, it's still within the Schengen Zone. That means no border formalities in Vienna; just find your next gate and go.

Answer (score 3):

You may be okay: Vienna states a minimum connection time of 25 minutes for some connections. See https://www.viennaairport.com/en/passengers/arrival__departure/transfer

The fact that the airline booked you on one ticket is encouraging: it's a legal connection. Rebooking a passenger and/or having to put them in a hotel is expensive for the airlines. If that happens frequently they would increase the connection time and stop selling this type of ticket. Keep in mind that actual schedules are often padded: makes their on-time record look better and reduces delay penalties. A flight where all goes "as planned" arrives significantly earlier than scheduled.

This being said: everything needs to go "as planned" and any delay or hiccup will throw you off.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Schengen connection, you're probably fine if there are no delays to the incoming flight.

Nevertheless, if you do miss it, just go to the airline desk and they'll rebook you on the next connection.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience - you will not make it since you will have to go through additional security again and passport control for your international flight. The absolute minimum I ever made it in was 40 minutes and that was with SKIPPING lines and RUNNING like crazy through the airport. (In my experience in those cases my suitcases didn't make it anyways)

So you should reach out to your airline (now or at the airport that day) and they will (should !!!) book you on a different flight. You could also do that in Vienna when you actually miss your flight (have done that before), but I recommend getting it done before because it will be less stressful for you! Hope that helped! :)

P.S. As of my knowledge; airlines are required to re-book you and give you at least 1 hour to change flights.

Comment: If I recall correctly, whether additional security is required depends on the countries in question.  I do not remember having to go through additional security in Vienna except when flying to the US.  Some airports also require certain arriving passengers to clear additional security on arrival, if the security measures at their departure airport are not considered to be adequate, but when arriving in Vienna from the US or from Sarajevo, which I've done many times, this is not necessary.  Furthermore, there is no passport control for an international-to-international transfer.

Comment: "So you should reach out to your airline (now or at the airport that day) and they will (should !!!) book you on a different flight" Unnecessary - it's a waste of time if OP would've made it, and if they don't, they'll get on the next one anyway